# How to filter a pandas dataframe if a column is a list

Tags: pandas

In the dataframe that comes from 
http:bit.ly/imdbratings
one column, actors_list,  is a list of the actors in the movie.
How do I filter the dataframe for movies where Al Pacino took part?
e.g.  [u'Marlon Brando', u'Al Pacino', u'James Caan']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use filtering with a `map` function inside it. Suppose you are looking for actor number 32:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
                   'Actors':[[1,2,3],[2,4,3],[3,4,5,32,1],[4,5,2,3],[102,302],[1,2,3,32,5]]})
df[df['Actors'].map(lambda x: 32 in x)]
```

Output:

```
  name            Actors
2    C  [3, 4, 5, 32, 1]
5    F  [1, 2, 3, 32, 5]
```

Or if you want to check if at least one actor from the list of actors you wish is present in the movies then use `any` in combination with lambda:

```
important_actors = [32,3]
print(df[df['Actors'].map(lambda x: any(i in x for i in important_actors))])
```

Output:

```
  name            Actors
0    A         [1, 2, 3]
1    B         [2, 4, 3]
2    C  [3, 4, 5, 32, 1]
3    D      [4, 5, 2, 3]
5    F  [1, 2, 3, 32, 5]
```

The structure is that... You can now change `any` for `all` if you wish to filter the movies where all actors are in them, and so on... Feel free to leave a comment if you need further explanation/have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do string `contains`.

```
l=[u'Marlon Brando', u'Al Pacino', u'James Caan']
m=df['actors_list'].str.join('|').str.contains('|'.join(l))
df=df[m]
```

Or

```
m=pd.DataFrame(df['actors_list'].tolist()).isin(l).any(1)
df=df[m.values]
```

Comment: Gives me an error  Why doesn't this work: movies[    u'Al Pacino' in movies['actors_list'].tolist() ]

Comment: @jkally list type column  can not check like what you did